# Chrome localStorage Limits

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

From what I have understood, and been able to test, thus far Chrome (v 19 on Windows) "limits" local storage to 2.49 Mb, a figure I have verified for myself.  However, the storage scenario I have to deal with is rather more complicted.  I have an IDE like interface for which I am fetching context sensitive help from the server when the user hovers over something relevant.  Once this is done I store that help text (HTML typically between 120 and 1024 chars) to localStorage.  No problems thus far.  However, the IDE is a very large and complex one and in due course the localStorage will contain 100s or even 1000s of keys.  What is not clear to me is this -  will the results of the rather rudimentary localStorage limits tests (my own and ones I ran into on the web) still be valid - the tests are done by storing a long char string under one key which is significantly different from what I have described above.  I assume that at the very least there is an overhead associated with the space consumed by key storage itself.

Comment: What code are you using to test local storage?... its been a while since I tested but I'm almost positive that Chrome will store at least 5Mb.

Comment: Hmm, it appears you are correct... the storage size in Chrome is about 1/2 of what Firefox supports.  You can test any browser here: http://arty.name/localstorage.html

Comment: If my memory serves me right, it's based on number of bytes, and the default character encoding used by Chrome for local storage is 16 bit, which is why it's only half of what Firefox uses. But if anybody have any updated pointers to the limit, I'm all ears!